# ing + while + ing

Tags: conjunctions

> He was gesturing to me **while** he was batting.
>
> He was singing **while** having bath.
>
> He was singing **while** I was having bath.

Can **while** be used in this manner?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, i see no issue in using while like this. The sentences seem fine

Comment: Your second and third sentences need an indefinite article: ***a*** *bath*.

Answer (score 1):

While as a conjunction means **at the same time as something else is happening**.

> e.g. You can go swimming while I am having lunch.
>   
>  yes you can use them in the way you have used them